# Linear gradient fill with multiple stops

Tags: tikz-pgf

Looking for a tikz-pgf solution to generate shapes with linear gradient fills that have multiple stops.  So far I am able to get a single "stripe" with the following code snippet

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
    \fill [left color=black,right color=black,middle color=white,shading angle=80] (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces the following picture
[image: Bar with gradient fill produced with tikz]

What I would like is an image with multiple gradient stops like the image below with the ability to vary the number of stops and their colors.

[image: Multiple gradient stops]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get shadings of this type with `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{bwbwb}{4cm}{color(0cm)=(black); 
color(2cm)=(black); 
color(2.5cm)=(white); color(3cm)=(black); color(3.5cm)=(white); 
color(4cm)=(black);color(6cm)=(black)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[shading=bwbwb,shading angle=-20]  (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that's perfect.