# Tikz shading: understanding the position of color placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

This is a follow-up question to another one [I asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646692/tikz-gradient-with-3-or-more-colors-using-pgfdeclarehorizontalshading). I feel like that other question still needs a proper answer, and hopefully this current more specific question will help achieve that. The general purpose is to fully understand how to specify color placement in a shading in order to produce the desired outcome. Athough often times examples use shadings with symmetrical patterns easily enough, when I try to actually control which zones start and end certain colors I am unable to get an understanding of how this works.

Here is a specific example with a 10cm bar (units of 1cm are plotted right under it) for which I would expect the 3 shaded zones to be in the center, which they are not:

[MWE on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rrgptzkfmspp)

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{grad3}{2cm}{
    color(0cm)=(white);
    color(0.28cm)=(white);color(0.29cm)=(black);color(0.31cm)=(black);color(0.32cm)=(white);
    color(0.48cm)=(white);color(0.49cm)=(black);color(0.51cm)=(black);color(0.52cm)=(white);
    color(0.68cm)=(white);color(0.69cm)=(black);color(0.71cm)=(black);color(0.72cm)=(white);
    color(1cm)=(white)
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[shading=grad3,shading angle=0] (current page.north west) ++ (2cm,-6cm) rectangle ++ (10cm,-2cm);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,10}
        \draw[draw=black] (current page.north west) ++ (2cm+\i cm,-8cm) rectangle ++( 0cm,-1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot from Overleaf:
[image: Screenshot of LaTeX output from Overleaf]

The [PGF/TIKZ manual](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) does specify how shadings get clipped (section 114.3, pages 1199-1201), and that is a piece of information to take into account I believe when entering the start and end of a zone. But this is not the issue at hand since even when only including the central zone (in the 49%-51% portion) the zone is not centered... Why?

Also, the three zones are supposed to occupy 4% of the space (e.g. from 0.48cm to 0.52cm), which might double to 8% due to the fact that shade clipping leaves only 50% visible (when there is, as in my case, no rotation). But here, each zone can clearly be seen occupying more than a 1cm notch, i.e. more than 10%.

NB: if attempting to answer this, please also try asymmetric placements such as 30%-70% to make sure the recipe works.

---

**[EDIT 1]**
As noted in comments by Rmano, different viewers produce diffent outputs. The above screenshot is from Overleaf; below is the screenshot I get using TeXstudio on my computer.
Screenshot from TeXstudio:
[image: Screenshot of LaTeX output from TeXstudio]

As you can tell, the centering problem persists, although the width of each band now seems to be about right.

Comment: Hi, which PDF viewer are you using? I have completely different outcomes with `evince` and `okular` (and different between them...) (I'm quite surprised...)

Comment: @Rmano You are correct: the above screenshot is from Overleaf. When I use TeXstudio I get something much closer to the 4% width anticipated for each band, but I still have the centering problem (which is my main issue in understanding positioning). I have edited my question to include your important observation, thanks!

Comment: I think I remember that the clipping is made letting out the first 25% and the last 25% of the gradient. I have no pc now, but what happens if you define your shadows between 0.5cm and 1.5cm? (Given that the full length is 2cm?)

Comment: @Rmano I am not sure what you mean by "full length", but "\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{grad3}{2cm}" declares a shading with a 2cm height, not length. My understanding is that the length scales to whatever is indicated by the boundaries of the different colors. The 25%-75% clipping you mention is exactly what I am referring to in the manual, and that is why I made sure that all my coordinates were well within that 25%-75% zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your other question. You get the probably wanted result if you stick to an 100bp shading and don't enlarge your path with a move-to operation. But be aware that there can be rounding errors ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{grad3}{100bp}{
    color(0bp)=(white);
    color(28bp)=(white);color(29bp)=(black);color(31bp)=(black);color(32bp)=(white);
    color(48bp)=(white);color(49bp)=(black);color(51bp)=(black);color(52bp)=(white);
    color(68bp)=(white);color(69bp)=(black);color(71bp)=(black);color(72bp)=(white);
    color(100bp)=(white)
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[shading=grad3,shading angle=0] ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-6cm]current page.north west) rectangle ++ (10cm,-2cm);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,10}
        \draw[draw=black] (current page.north west) ++ (2cm+\i cm,-8cm) rectangle ++( 0cm,-1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The key seems to be to use "shift" rather than the "moveTo" (++) in coordinates, thanks this was driving me nuts!